# Trying to build a grid of divs with opacity changing on hover

Tags: jquery, opacity

please bear with me because this is the first script I'm trying to build from scratch so it sucks and I'm aware of this.

What I'm trying to create is: a grid of 9 divs, when the mouse hovers on a div the other 8 fade to .25 opacity. Then as long as the mouse stays on the grid the "1" opacity level just follows the mouse. Wherever the mouse is you have 1 (actually .999) opacity, elsewhere you have .25.

When the mouse exits completely from the grid area, all the divs switch back to 1 opacity.

I know it's quite convoluted so I created a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cooperdale/AKuKx/15/

It actually works if you move slowly, but the script is too unreliable: if you move the mouse faster, you can get unpredictable results such as a group of divs being "on (1)" and the other divs "off (0.25)".

This is the script I wrote:

```
    $(function() {

    $('#jazzmen').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#sq1').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq2').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq3').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq4').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq5').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq6').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq7').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq8').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $('#sq9').css({ opacity: 1 });
    }
    );


  $('.music9').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).css('opacity') == 1) {
        $(this).css({ opacity: 0.999 });
        if (this.id !== 'sq1') {
            $('#sq1').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq2') {
            $('#sq2').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq3') {
            $('#sq3').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq4') {
            $('#sq4').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }        
        if (this.id !== 'sq5') {
            $('#sq5').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq6') {
            $('#sq6').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq7') {
            $('#sq7').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }            
        if (this.id !== 'sq8') {
            $('#sq8').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq9') {
            $('#sq9').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 500);
        }
     }

     if ($(this).css('opacity') == 0.25) {
         $(this).animate({opacity: 0.999}, 200);

        if (this.id !== 'sq1') {
            $('#sq1').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq2') {
            $('#sq2').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq3') {
            $('#sq3').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq4') {
            $('#sq4').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }        
        if (this.id !== 'sq5') {
            $('#sq5').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq6') {
            $('#sq6').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq7') {
            $('#sq7').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }            
        if (this.id !== 'sq8') {
            $('#sq8').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
        if (this.id !== 'sq9') {
            $('#sq9').animate({opacity: 0.25}, 10);
        }
    }

  }

  );
});
```

I guess the script could be made much better by using vectors or something. I hope somebody can help me make this more reliable, thanks guys.

Comment: You will run into errors because animate does not set the opacity instantly but fades over 500ms. Thus you will have cases in your code where where your node .25 or 1.

Comment: The real issue actually comes up when the mouse leaves the grid. The other functionality is fine, but sometimes when the mouse leaves the grid one or more divs won't return to 1 opacity.
As you see, when the mouse leaves the grid the effect is instantaneous and animate isn't used. But that's where the actual problems begin, so I don't think animate is the real issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$('.music9')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.999 })
               .siblings().stop().animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.music9').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.999 });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AKuKx/20/)

Comment: It works, and it's about 95% shorter than mine! Thanks! Now I'll look at the documentation and figure out what it does :).
In your example opacity can be set to 1 instead of .999 with no problems, I was using .999 to avoid a problem I had in the beginning.